# Move GhostDoc documentation to <include> tag file

Tags: ghostdoc

So I have GhostDoc Pro and auto documented a project. Great.
The results are, as it says in the C# documentation [put it all together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#put-it-all-together) verbose compared to the code. Therefore I would like to use the [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#include) tag and a separate file for the documentation to make my classes less documentation heavy.

All the classes are auto documented, but the documentation goes into class include files, like this:

```
/// <include file='MyMathClass.xml' path='docs/members[@name="math"]/Math/*'/>
... some code ...
```

and another class

```
/// <include file='MyArtClass.xml' path='docs/members[@name="art"]/Art/*'/>
... some code ...
```

Is there a feature to do this, or am I going to have to move every documentation tag by hand? I would like every class to have its own include file.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is coming but the current version of GhostDoc doesn't support the